# Excel VBA cell.Formula for each row in a column (as If I dragged down the formula)

Tags: vba, excel

How could I make the G2 value in this code to simulate it being dragged down in excel, as of right now the formula only test for G2 in each row it is inserted into where I rather the code test according to each row, i.e. G2,G3,G4,G5.. (only column G)

```
    LASTROW2 = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range("J2:J" & LASTROW2)
For Each cell In rng2
       cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],$G:$I,2,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(RC[-8],$A:$C,2,FALSE)"
 Next cell
```

Right now I receive an `application defined error` with the cell.FormulaR1C1 and I have never debugged one of these error codes before

Comment: I think you are looking for the `FillDown` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas

Comment: you need to make the entire formula `R1C1` notation. Also there's no need for a loop, you can write directly to rng2.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use A1 references: `rng2.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,$G:$I,2,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(B2,$A:$C,2,FALSE)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `R1C1` notation to the entire range directly. Also, the formula you used mixed `A1` and `R1C1` notation, which will never work.

```
Set rng2 = Range("J2:J" & LASTROW2)
rng2.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],C[-4]:C[-1],2,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(RC[-8],C[-9]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: I would have done the absolute version `C7:C9` instead the relative `C[-4]:C[-1]` but that's just me. Oh and to Quote Ralph on a previous question, "Good Job, Scott." :P.

Comment: @ScottCraner what's the difference?

Comment: @phillipsK - if you drag the formula left-to-right or right-to-left, the relative version will move columns as you drag. the absolute will always retain the same columns. it shouldn't matter in this case, but its just like using `$A:$C` (absolute) for `A:C` (relative)

Comment: To add what Scott said, The absolute version requires the actual column and row number and not the relative to the parent cell.  It is denoted by removing the `[]`. @phillipsK