# Excel: Use table header in formula as reference for multiple rows calculation

Tags: vba, excel, header, excel-formula

I have 1 table named table1. It has multiple columns. I have another table named table2 where I want to fill a column with column header named ColB using a formula referencing to the cells in table1 with column header named ColA. table1 looks like this:

```
    ColA ...
---------------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    .
    .
    .
```

The column ColB I want to fill has a formula, where each cell references multiple rows to table1, ColA. The formula for the 1st row of the ColB in table2 is simply a sum operation like this: (ColA row 1) + (ColA row 2) + (ColA row 3). And the formula for the 2nd row of ColB in table2 will follow as (ColA row 2) + (ColA row 3) + (ColA row 4), the rest of the column should follow this pattern.

I do not want to use cell references like for eg. A1, A2, C3... 
Is there a way to do this without using loop in VBA? Although I am using VBA, I want to simply apply the first formula in the first row of ColB, then autofill the formula throughout the ColB.

Comment: yes, use `AutoFill` for Colb in Table B. Read about `AutoFill` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas

Comment: I don't think it is so simple. The link you referred to uses the A1 cell references. I want to use table header references.