# Filling the formulas in excel through access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to fill formulas in excel sheet from access db VBA.I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas)

Here is my code

```
   Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim strFormulas(1 To 4) As Variant

   txtcatpath = Form_Bom.Excelpath.Value

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
      Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(txtcatpath) 
     .Visible = True
End With
 With wb.Sheets("common based") 
    strFormulas(1) = "=IF(F4<>F5,E4,E4&""&H5)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=VLOOKUP(J4,F:H,3,FALSE)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=IF(COUNTIF(F4:F900,F4)=1,F4,"")"
    strFormulas(4) = "=SUMIF(F:F,J4,G:G)"
    .Range("H4:K4").Formula = strFormulas
    .Range("H4:K" & LRow & "").FillDown
End With
```

When debugging my code is getting broken in `.Range("H4:K4").Formula = strFormulas`. How do i fill the columns with the formula.

Comment: Do you mean you want `H4:K4` to be `H4 = strFormula(1)`, `I4 = strFormulas(2)`, etc.?

Comment: @ BruceWayne  Yes , in strFormulas(1) i'm trying to concate E4&""&H5, where the error is getting. Access is not allowing me to put E4&"_"&H5 between. How do i put underscore between E4 and E5

Comment: When using quotes inside a formula, you need to "double up", otherwise VBA thinks your formula ended. Try `"=IF(F4<>F5,E4,E4&""_""&H5)"`

Comment: Thank you , worked perfect and saved my time

Comment: Does this line: `.Range("H4:K4").Formula = strFormulas` successfully fill H4 with strFormula(1), I4 with strFormula(2), J4 with 3, and K4 with 4?

Comment: @ BruceWayne Yes it is

Comment: That's neat, I didn't you you could do that. Learned something new :tumbsup:

Comment: @ BruceWayne You can do `arr() = range("a1:a10").value` also, and the same put back, `so arr(5)="new val":range("a1:a10").value=arr`