# Banker Rounding in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a Mortgage Amortization calculator using `VBA`.
When I type the formulas in the worksheet and reference each cell to the formula then my calculator works fine. It requires me to drag all my formulas down to duration of the loan.
For example, if loan duration is 300 months, I can just drag the formulas to say cell number 300 and it will work fine.

PROBLEM: When I use `VBA` code to do the same I get essentially a rounding problem where after the end of the term, I don't get a balance of 0.00. I have tried both normal round function and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round` and it still yields the same result.
Why do my calculations work on the worksheet but when translated into VBA code I get different results?
Link to screenshot of my spreadsheet which corresponds to the code: 
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loan2()

Dim i As Integer, LD As Integer
LD = Range("C5").Value
Range("B11", "G1000").ClearContents
Range("B11", "G1000").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For i = 1 To LD
    Cells(10 + i, 2).Value = i 'Payment Period
    Cells(10 + i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("C7").Value, 2) 'Monthly Payment
    Cells(10 + i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Cells(10 + i - 1, 6) * (Range("C4").Value / 12), 2) 'Interest payment
    Cells(10 + i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Cells(10 + i, 3).Value - Cells(10 + i, 5).Value, 2) 'Principle payment
    Cells(10 + i, 6).Value = Cells(10 + i - 1, 6).Value - Cells(10 + i, 4).Value 'Balance
    Cells(10 + i, 7) = Cells(10 + i, 4).Value + Cells(10 + i, 5).Value 'Sum of principle and interest.
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you can use `For i = 11 to LD` instead of `i = 1` and then use `i` instead of `10+i`. Also, could you provide the formula that you use and it works?

Comment: I might be missing the obvious here but if LD = 12 then that would only go 1 step? 

The formulas: At cell C7, to calculate the monthly payment we use: =C6*((C4/12)*(1+(C4/12))^(C5))/((1+(C4/12))^(C5) - 1)

EDIT: Pressed enter early.
Monthly Payment = Principle*(i(1+i)^loan duration)/((1+i)^loan duration) -1), where i = Annual interest/12

Comment: You are right. So instead of using `LD` use `LD +10`. To be fair, your code works fine the way it is. I just thing this would make it look nicer instead of having `10+` everywhere. It's more like a personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative to the worksheet function (avoiding bankers' rounding):**

```
Function roundIt(ByVal d As Double, ByVal nDigits As Integer) As Double
' Purpose: avoid so called bankers' rounding in VBA (5 always rounds even)
If nDigits > 0 Then
   ' if european colon instead of point separartor
   ' roundIt= val(Replace(Format(d, "0." & String(nDigits, "0")), ",", "."))
     roundIt= val(Format(d, "0." & String(nDigits, "0")))
Else
   ' if european colon instead of point separartor
   ' roundIt =  val(Replace(Format(d / (10 ^ nDigits), "0."), ",", "."))
   roundIt = val(Format(d / (10 ^ nDigits), "0."))
End If
End Function
```

Always use "Option explicit" to check your declarations.
Code gets more readable if you use a Type structure.
Write this in the **declaration head** of your module.

```
Option Explicit

Type TLoan
   Interest       As Double
   LD             As Integer
   Principal      As Double
   Annuity        As Double
End Type
```

**Here is your code with some additions**

```
Sub Loan2()
Dim loan As TLoan                                   ' declare loan as of type TLoan
Dim i As Integer                                    ' no more use for LD ", LD As Integer"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")     ' fully qualified range

With loan
  .Interest = ws.Range("C4").Value
  .LD = ws.Range("C5").Value
  .Principal = ws.Range("C6").Value
  .Annuity = ws.Range("C7").Value
End With

With ws
  .Range("B10").Value = 0
  .Range("F10").Value = loan.Principal              ' principal
  .Range("B11", "G1000").ClearContents
  .Range("B11", "G1000").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

  For i = 1 To loan.LD
    .Cells(10 + i, 2).Value = i                     'Payment Period
    .Cells(10 + i, 3) = roundIt(loan.Annuity, 2)   'Monthly Payment
    .Cells(10 + i, 5) = roundIt(.Cells(10 + i - 1, 6) * (loan.Interest / 12), 2) 'Interest payment
    .Cells(10 + i, 4) = roundIt(.Cells(10 + i, 3).Value - .Cells(10 + i, 5).Value, 2) 'Principle payment
    .Cells(10 + i, 6).Value = Cells(10 + i - 1, 6).Value - .Cells(10 + i, 4).Value    'Balance
    .Cells(10 + i, 7) = .Cells(10 + i, 4).Value + .Cells(10 + i, 5).Value             'Sum of principle and interest.
  Next i
End With
End Sub
```

**Additional tip (autofill Routine)**

Try to use an autofill routine as shown in "Excel-VBA-autofill multiple cells with formula [Excel VBA: AutoFill Multiple Cells with Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas), if you want to include formulas instead of pure values.

**Attention:** This code refers to another problem with different ranges! Try and play around.

```
Sub FillDown()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formeln")
    strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(A2:B2)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=A2/B2"
'    Pattern Formulas
    .Range("C2:E2").Formula = strFormulas
'    AutoFill Target
    .Range("C2:E11").FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the roundIt code. It still seems to be giving the same problem. I don't understand why when cell referencing the formulas in the worksheet and dragging it doesn't yield the same 'numerical' error. I will have to go through each line one by one and see where the problem is.

Comment: I'll add a more readable approach similar to yours to my answer. It's better code style to use fully qualified reference to a range. BTW, An annuity formula will always have some rounding differences, if it's not to much you will add/substract this in the last line.

Comment: There is also the short version `.Range("C2:E11").Formula = Array("=SUM(A2:B2)", "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)", "=A2/B2")` or `.Range("C2:E11").Formula = [{"=SUM(A2:B2)", "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)", "=A2/B2"}]`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the detailed reply. The neatness of your code gives me a lot to learn from! It still yields the same error I occurred from my original code. I will play around with AutoFill routine to see if I can learn something new which will assist me in getting a correct solution

Comment: @dantab22, it would help if you show the underlying formulas as well as the set formatting in D11:G11 to analyze the differences. As I mentioned already, any rounding will lead to a (minimal) difference. I suppose that you didn't round your cell range, so that you see only formatted values (only rounded in Display) which , in fact, are calculated with their mathematical values. I think this to be an acceptable answer.