# Filling formulas automatically as data increase and sort dynamically

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I want to sort data in a worksheet, which gets new rows daily, in a second worksheet.

The problem is, if I use the SMALL()-function and fill the cells automatically till the last row (A102482 or something like that), my file gets very huge and laggy (>20mb).

Of course the person adding a new line could expand the formula in the second worksheet into a new row, but this is not userfriendly at all!

What would be the best solution? I thought about vba-code, which counts the entries in the first worksheet, and then runs a code like this

```
for (i to numberrows; i++) { SMALL(A + i + 2*3, i) }
```

filling the first few rows in the second worksheet so the excel-file doesn't get too big...

Thanks in advance!

Edit.:

To be more specific:

What I'm asking excel to do is copy a worksheet and have the rows sorted on the second worksheet. And as the table expends, of course the sorted table has more values. This process should be done automatically, with the user only entering new data in the first worksheet and seeing the results in the second worksheet. Having the second worksheet's cells all already populates witht the SMALL() function is not an option, as this would work in my case, but this is way too slow and the files get too big...

Comment: first off, **that's not VBA**.  Besides that, I would just prepare for the maximum amount of data, and just keep formulas in **all** the appropriate cells, using conditional formatting or an `if` statement to hide formulas for rows that don't have data yet.

Comment: If you format the data range as a table Excel will automatically enter formulas as the new rows are entered.

Comment: "If you format the data range as a table Excel will automatically enter formulas as the new rows are entered." What do you mean? Could you explain in more detail please?

Comment: " I would just prepare for the maximum amount of data, and just keep formulas in all the appropriate cells" - the maximum data is until the last row of excel... so if i copy the formula to all cells, the calculations will be already really slow, from the first entry onwards...

Comment: Select any single cell in your range, then from the [Home] Ribbon, under the [Styles] group, select [Format as Table]. Go to the table's bottom-right cell, hit TAB. A new row is inserted, and your formulas followed. If not, delete the formulas and re-type them. You should only need to enter a formula in a single row to populate the entire table.

Comment: In any case, your question is way too broad to be answerable in this site's Q&A format.

Comment: You are right. Basically what I'm asking excel to do is copy a worksheet and have the rows sorted on the second worksheet. And as the table expends, of course the sorted table has more values. This process should be done automatically, with the user only entering new data in the first worksheet and seeing the results in the second worksheet... I hope this is specific enough!

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: `maximum data is until the last row of excel` ... if you're planning ahead **to store a million+ records in an Excel sheet**, then you have some fundamental organizational flaws that should be re-thought before you proceed any further.

Comment: Let it be 1000-5000 rows/year. This "maximum" form is already really slow with the 5000 rows already being filled with formulas - that's why i consecutively want to fill the data automatically, so the last 4000 rows don't bother the CPU with nonsense-calculations as only the first 1000 matter... Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I disagree with the folks who say that it's a simple matter of filling-down (i.e. duplicate question)... the user inputs need to be sorted into their correct location on the report sheet.  That's not possible without a processing step in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the second table, the dependent one, out of a PivotTable.

This will grow and shrink with the first sheet every time you refresh the data, which can be set to automatically refresh when you open the file.  Here's how:

Use "Insert > Table" to format the first list.  Then use "Summarize with PivotTable" or "Insert > PivotTable" (2 names for the same feature) to put your PivotTable on the next sheet.

[image: Make your data into a table]

Put all the columns you want in the second sheet under "Row Labels" on the PivotTable wizard thingy that appears.

[image]

Under PivotTable Tools > Design > Layout > Subtotals, choose "Do not show subtotals."
Under PivotTable Tools > Design > Layout > Grand Totals, choose "Off for Rows and Columns."
Under PivotTable Tools > Design > Layout > Report Layout, choose "Show in Tabular Form."

[image: Here's what you get]

Note that if you don't have something unique at the top of the list in Row Labels, similar to "ID" in my example (  =ROW()  ), the PivotTable will do intelligent things with the data that you may not want.

Here's how to get the thing to refresh automatically when the file opens.  Alternately, you right-click on the table and choose "refresh".

[image: PivotTable options]
[image: Refresh data on file open]

If you wanted to refresh the PivotTable every time the data changes, put

```
Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
```

(substituting "Sheet2" with the name of the sheet where the table appears; activating the data sheet on the left side; select Worksheet on the first pull-down, and select Change on the second pull-down to access the Sub Worksheet_Change code area)

...here:

[image: Refresh PivotTable on data changes]

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me already together with the linked answer, the only disadvantage using this method is that the dependent table doesn't get updated automatically, but this is a crucial element in my table

Comment: If you like everything else than the way it gets updated, then maybe you can do a code that refreshes the pivottable whenever the data changes--- that would be very simple, I think.  I think the PivotTable has the advantage of your solution being 100% within Excel's pre-built features.

Comment: I added this feature to the Answer above.  I don't know if this will slow down the worksheet too much, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer here:

[Excel VBA: AutoFill Multiple Cells with Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas#comment33532249_22104743)

Sorry that my question was so misleading, basically the above answer is all I was asking for... Thanks for your time and your answers!

edit: linked to the specific post containing the answer

Comment: re: Link-only answers: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Notice [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas#comment33532249_22104743) on the post you're linking to.

Comment: Oh! If there's absolutely no data processing other than to sort the table, then yes!  Just make a table; add the inputs at the bottom; and sort... done!  I have a table like this; I make it sort automatically every time I hit "save".