# Excel - Remove Duplicates, Combination of Values

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking your time by reading my question, since it's possible this was already posted. Let's say I got this data and just want to keep one unique value from both columns and delete the others, what is the easiest way to do that?

[image]

Thanks for your attention,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the zillion possibilities, you could do a PivotTable.  Please see my explanation [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415482/filling-formulas-automatically-as-data-increase-and-sort-dynamically/49416664#49416664)

Comment: Yeah that is one, my problem is that they are around 34,000 lines. Means a lot.

Comment: PivotTable is intended for this kind of stuff (large datasets).  Your data won't have a unique column in the final report, so it will only show what's unique-in-combination.  You can even tell it to count how many times each combination shows up.

Comment: I am telling everybody these days how much I love the Excel Table feature (Insert > Table).  Using Excel Table will make your source data grow whenever you add lines; just hit refresh on the PivotTable to grab the new values.

Answer (score 2):

Among the zillion possibilities, you could use Data > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates on both columns selected together.

[image: Remove Duplicates]

Comment: Great answers, I honestly suck using Excel. Thank you

Comment: Why not remove duplicates using both columns?

Comment: Whoa, that works better.  Answer edited to avoid red herring.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this VBA code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim lastRow As Long, letters As Variant, arr As New Collection, i As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

letters = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastRow
    arr.Add letters(i, 1) & letters(i, 2), letters(i, 1) & letters(i, 2)
Next

For i = 1 To arr.Count
    Cells(i, 3) = Left(arr(i), 1)
    Cells(i, 4) = Right(arr(i), 1)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So that's how to use a collection.

Comment: It's just a short-hand for `Dim arr As Collection Set arr = New Collection`

Comment: I like it.  Why are there two inputs at your arr.Add?

Comment: Shorthand to be avoided!

Answer (score 2):

To place the unique list in columns C & D, select the data range then use Data, Sort & Filter, Advanced Filter, Copy to a new location, Unique records only.

[image]