# How to create a formula in excel to verify data pairs and list missing pairs?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula in excel to verify pairs in a data set, since I believe there is missing data.  For example (see example below), for each "Ordered" item with an ID of "100" there should be a matching "Actual" with an ID of "100".  I would like a list of all "Actual" items without matching "Ordered" items.

An example of data set and expected result of formula:

```
Name    ID
Ordered 100
Ordered 100
Ordered 100
Actual  100
Actual  100
Actual  100
Ordered 102
Ordered 102
Ordered 103
Actual  103

Pass        Fail
100         102
103
```

If there are any resources available on this already, please let me know.  I could not find anything on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you re-design your table like in the following example:

```
Key | Ordered | Actual |  ID
----+---------+--------+----
001 |       1 |      1 | 100
002 |       1 |      1 | 100
003 |       1 |      1 | 100
004 |       1 |      0 | 102
005 |       1 |      0 | 102
006 |       1 |      1 | 103
```

You just put a filter on "Ordered=1" and "Actual=0".

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This data set is an abstracted version of how it is set up in a database, in which "Ordered" and "Actual" are in one column.  If there is a way to use an excel formula for this, I can apply it when running reports.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to turn your data into a PivotTable which summarizes the entries according to ID, status, or whatever else you wish.

The nice thing about PivotTables is that they can probably accept the data you showed above without further formatting.  The annoying thing is that you have to right-click and refresh a PivotTable to update it... it doesn't auto-calculate like a formula.

Once you have the PivotTable formatted exactly the way you want, then outside the PivotTable you make equations that check whether the line passes.  For instance, you might subtract the 'Count of ID X that is Actual' from the 'Count of ID X that is Ordered', then do the same for Y, Z, etc.  Anything that's zero is fine!

[Click to read some information I wrote about PivotTables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415482/filling-formulas-automatically-as-data-increase-and-sort-dynamically/49416664#49416664)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! A PivotTable is good place to start.  Is there a way I can apply a function that does a COUNT on both "Actual" and "Ordered" in each ID field?  If "Actual" or "Ordered" COUNT equals 0 then list ID (since "Actual" and "Ordered" for each ID should NOT equal 0).  The issue I am having is the result will still be even if "Actual" or "Ordered" COUNT = 0 (see ID 102 for instance - count is still even with missing Actual count) and I can't filter out the bad data.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make a summary table below, having each ID in question listed.  Then you use sum() and if(), as array functions, to count the results.  For instance (halfway done for you below):

```
   A         B
1  Name      ID
2  Ordered  100
3  Ordered  101
4  Ordered  102
5  Actual   100

...

20 100      ={sum(if(if($B$2:$B$5=$A20,$A$2:$A$5,"")="Ordered",1,0)}
21 101      ={sum(if(if($B$2:$B$5=$A21,$A$2:$A$5,"")="Ordered",1,0)}
22 102      ={sum(if(if($B$2:$B$5=$A22,$A$2:$A$5,"")="Ordered",1,0)}
```

Note that using array functions like this requires you to finish typing with ctrl-shift-enter.  You know you did this correctly because Excel adds the {} brackets to the equation (you don't type those brackets).