# Auto fill formulas after inserting new rows at any rows (VBA for This Workbook or worksheet instead of macro module button)

Tags: excel, vba

To: Stackoverflow
i have searched in your library and found the relevant answer in [enter link description here][1]

[1]: [Excel VBA: AutoFill Multiple Cells with Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas). It is a beautiful code crafted and answered by Jerome Montino dated 2014-02-28, as follows:-

```
Sub FillDown()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(A2:B2)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=A2/B2"

    .Range("C2:E2").Formula = strFormulas
    .Range("C2:E11").FillDown
End With` 
End Sub
```

This code on the above works for me when i only have a few pre-determined strFormulas.

However i have more than 23 formulas per row. From time to time, i also need to add a few formulae to each row when the needs arise.

Because our project xlsm file is group collaboration, other users are free to add in rows either at the top (just below the header) or at the bottom last row or any rows in the middle.

I do not want to use macro module button to compose the code because most the users do not know how to use the button or could be quite forgetful to use such button. They only know how to use the "Insert shift cell down" right click button which will not auto-fill the formulas to the added row(s).

I do not want to turn these ranges of date into Table or listobject.

My objective is to **paste this VBA code into the worksheet or This Workbook** for it to work **without the users knowing it**.

Because of the frequent addition of formulas, it is not easy to keep track or upkeep 23 or more strFormulas if i were to use this code.

I would appreciate it if you could advise me a code that can be pasted in the worksheet or Workbook that is dynamic to cater for the above. Thank you.

**From Tan LC 2020-02-12**

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

Comment: To BigBen_thank you for your advise. As suggested, i went to look at the link but it did not show the relevant code. From LC Tan 2020-02-16