# Excel macro VBA add line below the previously added line and also copy format and formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro which adds a line whilst copying the format and formulas of the above line. This works fine and the code is below:

```
Sub New_Line()

Rows("7:7").Select
'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("7:7").Select   
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _  
       SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("G6:T6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G6:T7"), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("G7:T7").Select 
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    
End Sub
```

However, I want to add another line under the line I have just created using the macro above and so on, so that this can be a continuous thing and to also keep a running total using the formulas from the previously added line above (hope that makes sense). I can see where the issue is in the coding above, the macro will always add the line to row 7 and copy the formula/format from row 6. I've tried adding a +1 but no success, I considered a loop but that would confuse the macro run. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post two screenshots, one of before and one of after to clarify what is required. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67078950/edit) your post at any time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website and not sure how to post the screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, the curse of the macro recorder. Damn thing is best ignored except for some syntax sometimes!

Try this:

```
nRows = 13 'Define how may rows you are going to copy down

sRow = 7  'The starting row for the paste op (which will copy from sRow-1)

for iRows = 0 to nRows

    Rows(sRow+iRows-1).Copy
    Rows(sRow+iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Rows(sRow+iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

next iRows
```

As with any solution, I'd also recommend you fully qualify at least what worksheet you are in, i.e.

```
for iRows = 0 to nRows
    with Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Rows(sRow+iRows-1).Copy
        .Rows(sRow+iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Rows(sRow+iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    end with
next iRows
```

If not the workbook as well. It leaves you less vulnerable (but not bulletproof) to interaction with the PC fouling up your macro.

You can also try "FillDown" as per:
[Excel VBA: AutoFill Multiple Cells with Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104743/excel-vba-autofill-multiple-cells-with-formulas)

If you want it to restart from the last row each time you run it, then use the following for sRow

```
sRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks, Amiga500! I will have a go at that tomorrow morning and give an update.

Comment: The coding adds another line, but it continues to loop by adding the line on row 8/7 and copying line 6. Is there a way to continue to add lines in row 9, 10, 11 etc.?

Comment: Did you copy it right? Have you put iRow instead of iRows inside the loop?

It copies the line above to the line below here...

Comment: If I have the formula: "=PRODUCT(A6:C6,D5)" in cell D6, by the time I get to cell D20 its 4.7E+11 if I'm copying 1, 2 & 3 into cols A, B & C for each row...

Comment: I've added my code to the main answer. Thanks!

Comment: The formulas are standard math - =L7-SUMIF($L$3,E8,B8) - but I need L7, E8 and B8 to continue the +1 cell formula as I add new lines.

Comment: Sorry another point, what if I want to only copy and paste columns G:T and not A:F? But keep the same format for A:F as the above line?

Comment: That SUMIF formula is ok... as long as something else is driving changes in L7, E8 or B8. Otherwise it'll always give the same result.

Comment: Easiest way of fixing the formulas for columns A:F would be use absolute positions, i.e. $A$1 rather than A1

Then the copy op won't adjust the numbers within the formula.

If you want to maintain use of relatives, but copy it, then its a little more complex and needs a copy text operation

Comment: Genius! Thanks Amiga!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have used:

```
 Sub NewTry1()

nRows = 1 'Define how may rows you are going to copy down

sRow = 7  'The starting row for the paste op (which will copy from sRow-1)

For iRows = 0 To nRows

Rows(sRow + iRows - 1).Copy
Rows(sRow + iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Rows(sRow + iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

  Next iRows

  For iRows = 0 To nRows
   With Sheets("Main Sheet")
    .Rows(sRow + iRows - 1).Copy
    .Rows(sRow + iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Rows(sRow + iRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
End With
 Next iRows

 End Sub
```

I'm fairly new to VBA so apologies if I have misunderstood any area!

Comment: Because that is testing, I assume your just trying the unqualified and qualified approaches? You aren't expecting the second loop (using the With) to do anything different are you?

Increase nRows >1 if you want to get it to paste on down the sheet (13 if you wanted it to go to row 20) ... but otherwise its working fine here...??

Comment: Check that the formula you have in row 6 isn't using a fixed cell address and is using a relative cell address... i.e. A7 rather than $A$7.

Comment: It does work and it does copy and past the rows, however when I re-run the macro to add more lines below the ones previously added, it doesn't do this.

Comment: The formulas in row 6 use one fixed address -  =L7-SUMIF($L$3,E8,B8) - The fixed cell address is reference to an 8 digit code. I could replace the $L$3 with the code?

Comment: I've changed the fixed cell so that there are no fixed addresses in the formulas.

Comment: It'll never add  more formula beneath the ones in already - its set up to run to nRows only - you'd have to adjust it. Will do an edit to my original post

Comment: Thanks Amiga500, it's been frustrating and your help is much appreciated.